# What does "Wait State" access mean on a MCU's datasheet and how does it affect me?

Tags: microcontroller, avr

I'm considering using an AT32UC3B in my project (the Super OSD Pro version.) However, something about the datasheet has me worried.

Page 31

- 0 Wait State Access at up to 30 MHz in Worst Case Conditions
- 1 Wait State Access at up to 60 MHz in Worst Case Conditions

What is a "worst case condition"? The output stage for my OSD needs to be able run at 60 MIPS (the processor's maximum operating frequency), and I presume a "wait state" means it has to wait to load data from the memory... which would limit me to <60 MIPS.

I suppose, worst case, I could load the code into RAM and execute it from there (I presume this is possible with AVR32s?), but it still has me confused.

Comment: Execution from RAM is impossible in AVRs, though I haven't used AVR32s.  Are you using an OSD IC (e.g. MAX4455) for your OSD or bit banging a micro?

Comment: This is actually something that is very typical everywhere. This is partially why computer CPUs have a cache. You can pull data from a slower methods and stick it in cache that can be accessed very fast when the instruction needs it.

Comment: @Nick T MAX7456 is the new version :-)

Comment: @Nick T - AVR32 is very different to AVR.  They are more like Cortex M3 but with better low power modes (IMHO)

Comment: @Nick T, I am using a software OSD layer, written by myself. If you're interested, it is open source: http://code.google.com/p/super-osd.

Comment: I am wondering about the -1, can the voter please justify their choice?

Comment: @Thomas O, I think this is actually a really good question to be asking on here. However, you seem to be arguing with people about the answer. Usually that means that you already know the answer and are just posting to post. This usually will make people mad.

Comment: @Kellenjb I'm disagreeing about some things that aren't true, like PIC MCU's being unpredictable. Some MCU's aren't predictable but most are. The original question wasn't about this though, it was about whether wait states affect me.

Comment: @Thomas O, I didn't down vote you, I am just giving a possibility as to why you may have been. I think wait state very much is part of the discussion. It is telling you that for an instruction you place, you may have to wait an extra instruction cycle before getting your data. This wait state means that effectively you have instructions that take different amounts of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wait state is an extra bus clock cycle that is added to the memory access to allow time for the information to be extracted and appear on the processor bus.  This addition of wait states will limit your processing speed to less than 60MIPS (whatever that means).  The AVR32 has a banked/interleaved flash memory design so that the wait states are hidden for straight line code allowing it to access program flash at the full 60MHz but as soon as you execute a branch or CALL then this will break the interleaving and incur a wait state penalty.

The AVR32 can run code from its RAM but this is a somewhat limited resource on the 32B devices.

If you REALLY need the full 60MIP operation for your code to function then you will have problems.  How will you cope with interrupts taking processor time.....

Comment: He has actually mentioned before that on his lower end version he is at 80-90% CPU usage (on a slower processor I believe) and can't even have UART interrupt him. But here he says he needs all 60 MIPS. Not sure if hes trying to say hes at 100% cpu usage now or not.

Comment: Well then the very best of British to him - he will need it!!

Comment: This is quickly becoming a case of updating to better hardware, or make some sort of front end to service the I/O while you update a buffer.

Comment: Yeah, but that would require higher cost and board space which I am sure Thomas doesn't want.

Comment: MIPS is million of Instructions Per Seconds. For a comparison an Intel 486DX is about 54 MIPS.  An Intel i7 is above 75,000 MIPS.

Comment: @Kellenjb, 80% - 90% is an estimate. More optimised code is going to drop that down to 60% (for example, setting up a timer during the horizontal blanking interval instead of using a busy loop gives us an extra 200 * 15kHz = 3 MIPS.) That was with a 40 MIPS dsPIC, I'm using two chips on this board.

Comment: @Kortuk, I'm not sure that is relevant. I'm using a two chip solution, one handles IO and background tasks, one is dedicated entirely to the display.

Comment: @Kellenjb, board space is not critical, though smaller is better... again, this isn't really relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @Jim C, you are comparing a highly pipelined architecture and extremely expensive power hungry processor to an AVR32 - there is no comparison really.

Comment: @ThomasO, Stating that I think your solution may not exist with your hardware is relevant. When you said 80-90% before you stated it was heavily optimized.

Comment: @Jim C - I know that MIPS is a theoretical statement of performance.  The problem is that no processor EVER produces the theoretical MIPS level that the datasheet promises.  Real world factors like memory access and pipeline stalls together with interrupts all conspire to turn the MIPS number into a Meaningless Indicator of Processing Speed.

Comment: @ThomasO, @JimC, There is a comparison, it was done in MIPS.@Ian, I think he was just trying to give a reference scale.

Comment: @Kellenjb, also, I certainly can't afford to run at 30 MIPS. The output resolution has increased from 192x128 to 360x270 (about the highest possible, really) which squeezes me for every last instruction. The pixel clock is a mere 167ns (max), and I have to execute at least 7 instructions in this, so a minimum clock of 41 MHz.

Comment: @Ian, that does not apply for microcontrollers, which DO meet their MIPS specifications, as they usually do not have complex pipelines. You are probably talking about DMIPS?

Comment: I am using a 96 KB device. Even if I take up 2 bytes for each pixel to be output (as an instruction) it is just under 1 KB and I plan to use about 48 KB for the video memory.

Comment: @Thomas O - Microcontrollers are often worse having variable instruction processing times.  MSP430 has 1,2 and 3 clock instructions, 8051 has the same problem.

Comment: @Thomas O - is that the AT32UC3B512 part?  They are as rare as rocking horse poo.  min 6 months lead time

Comment: @Ian, not true for many processors. E.g., PIC for all instructions except branch are 4 cycle, similar for dsPIC (but 2 cycle instead of 4.) A microcontroller *must* have predictable timing as it is often used to bitbang serial protocols.

Comment: @Ian, using a AT32UC3B0512. The Pro version is at least 6 months from release. Lite version is using dsPIC33F, which is available now.

Comment: @Thomas O - If you have just 7 instructions per pixel clock then this sounds like one of those places where you have to use assembler and hand optimise to get the performance.

Comment: @Ian, which is exactly why I am using assembler! Other (graphics, drawing) code is written in C.

Comment: @thomas, saying that microcontrollers must have specific timing for functional reasons is more of a pipe-dream then a reality.

Comment: @Kortuk, it's not a pipe-dream for many MCU's! It's quite possible. I am doing it on a 40 MIPS dsPIC33F and it's working really well. I am not using branches for the output, just and/ior/mov.

Comment: @Thomas, I use PICs normally at my campus job, I know, but as you go higher end they become less dependable.

Comment: @Kortuk I haven't tried the PIC32 but I can confirm that all the way up to dsPIC33F the instruction execution is very much predictable.

Comment: @Thomas, I meant processors in general. It is significantly easier to make a improvement that happens 90% of the time then one that affects system wide.

Comment: @Kortuk, but if that improvement harms predicable code it is not implemented, which is my point - all the way up to the dsPIC33F series each instruction is entirely independent to the other in regards to timing.

Comment: @Thomas, If predictable was the most important things they would not be starting to make microcontrollers with a cache.

Answer (score 2):

Often operations are going to run faster then external memory. It is saying that when you are having to load from memory you will have to have wait states. Now they have in their datasheet that it is 30MHz no wait state from flash. they do have it optimized to allow pipelined access to flash to hide the delay cycle.

you are correct that ram is an option, but you should test your algorithm and see if you have issues. If you keep your keep branch instructions out of your code it should be able to pipeline and hide the wait states.

Comment: The output stage is branchless, but the computations (e.g. draw line) are typically not. Does this mean I'll get 60 MIPS most of the time, except when doing branches? (In which case, it would be very similar to PICmicros, and in fact many other processors.)

Comment: Yes, you are correctly interpreting that. when you are not having branches it should run without wait states.

Answer (score 0):

The AVR32A architecture is a 3 stage pipeline and it doesn't look like that model supports branch prediction so any branches in your code will stall the pipeline.  Also not all instructions are single cycle.

Generally speaking never choose a processor based on its MIPS rating.  In almost all real world scenarios you'll never get close to its theoretical peak MIPS rating.

Comment: Except when you're bit banging (which I am), in which case you use every last MIP!

Comment: @thomas, I think you misunderstood mark. He is telling you that directly using mips to correlate to operations is not a great practice as it will not reach that point, especially with memory pipelines and stall instructions.

Comment: yep, in addition you can't take an algorithm that work on a 50 MIPS PIC architecture and assume it would work on a 50MIPS AVR32 architecture.  The performance on various architectures can vary widely, especially in the microcontroller space where architectures themselves vary quite a lot.